# When to add "the" before a noun followed with a clause

Tags: grammar, nouns, clauses

E.g.

"Although they work in most cases, they cannot handle cases when a comment or script is broken by the cutting"

Should I put "the" between "handle" and "cases"?

Comment: No, it's not necessary. You can either specify those cases with _the_, or you can allow them to inferred with no article. No difference except rhythm, really.

Comment: What @John said - including his own (possibly unintended) implication that it could just as naturally be expressed as *they cannot handle **those** cases...* Which for no particular reason, I personally would follow with **where** rather than **when** (plus I'd probably drop the repetition of **cases**).

Answer (score 1):

I think both constructions are similarly clear to the reader.  For some people, I think there is a slight difference in connotation depending on what you mean by "most cases" in your opening clause.

If what you are referencing works in *all* cases except those in which a comment or script is broken by the cutting, then using "the" seems more appropriate to me.  If what you are referencing works in most cases but doesn't work in some cases, including *but not limited to* those in which a comment or script is broken by the cutting, then dropping "the" seems seems more appropriate to me.

"The" is a definite article and usually is used to refer to something specific.  In this case, for some, using the article "the" will emphasize the uniqueness of the cases that you mention.  In the first example, the cases that you mention are particularly unique.  Including a "the" makes this more apparent.  In the second example, the cases that you mention are different but not particularly unique.  Dropping the "the" de-emphasizes the uniqueness and might help some people to realize what you are referencing might not work in other scenarios as well.

[EDIT: Addendum]

It's not particularly relevant that you have noun followed by a clause.  For the purposes of this discussion, just treat the whole thing ("cases when a comment or script is broken by the cutting") as an object.

[Post edited to better deserve it's upvote!]

Comment: I can't quite make up my mind on this one, so I'm upvoting partly to counterbalance what I think is an unjustified downvote. I think it might help to imagine appending ***, for example*** to the original. I don't much like ***the*** in the first place (I'd much prefer either *nothing* or ***those***), but I think I like it even less after adding *, for example*. Which does rather support your case.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers.  I'm just starting to try to answer questions, so I'm not sure what constitutes a Good Response. Incidentally, I just edited this sentence in a paper I am writing, adding the "the": "While their model is more complex, we focus on *the* three key components of their model that relate to (a specific topic)." In this context, I think adding the "the" makes it clearer that the other components don't address the specific topic of the paper; however, that might be my biased perspective.

Comment: Well, presumably whoever downvoted you positively *disagreed* your distinction. Whereas I probably wouldn't have *upvoted* if it hadn't been to counteract that. But I'd *definitely* have upvoted if your first paragraph had explicitly made the point that *some* people might make the distinction (others might see it as purely a matter of style rather than meaning). Whatever - I think you've made a good start with this answer, and I look forward to reading more (I see from another browser window that there's already another one for me to check out, so I'll end this comment **here**! :)

Answer (score 0):

"*The*" is a definite article. So the only reason you might to add "*the*" is if you have mentioned "*broken comments or scripts by the cutting*" earlier in your writing.

For example:

> One way to create good comments and scripts is by using X, Y and Z.
>    Y is a great at handling cases where comments and scripts are broken by cutting but its does not work when…
>   X is the most widely used method. Although they work in most cases, they cannot handle **the** cases when a comment or script is broken by the cutting

Answer (score 0):

The sub-phrase "the cutting" seems odd, but we can assume that "the cutting" is some domain-specific term or a qualified noun (e.g. with an implied adjective) in a larger context.

So let's look at the core flow:

> Although they work in most cases, they cannot handle *the cases* when
>   a comment or script is broken by the cutting.

When spoken it sounds awkward. That's because it has a plurality conflict:

> *the case when a comment or script is broken by (the?) cutting*

This is because of the sub-phrase

> *comment or script **is** broken by the cutting*

has a singular subject.

*Although they work in most cases, they cannot handle the case when a comment or a script is broken by (the) cutting*

To clarify let's consider a slightly simpler phrase:

> Although they like most cars, they do not like the car when it *is* red

vs.

> Although they like most cars, they do not like the cars when they *are*
>   red

Please note that even though the compound phrase is singular, the phrase does not lose the sense of cardinality because the entire noun-phrase becomes a common noun.

Now for the *the* in *the cutting* and whether it's a qualified noun:

> Although they like most cars, they do not like the car when it *is* the colour red

vs.

> Although they like most cars, they do not like the cars when they *are* the colour
>   red

However if in a previous context "the colour red" was qualified you can drop "red":

> Although they like most cars, they do not like the car when it *is* the colour

vs.

> Although they like most cars, they do not like the cars when they *are* the colour

Applying this approach to your phrase then:

Proper construction would be either:

> Although they work in most cases, they cannot handle the cases when
>   comments or scripts are broken by the cutting.

OR

> Although they work in most cases, they cannot handle the case when a
>   comment or script is broken by the cutting.